Refeeding the values of overfull boxes from \message into my code. PDFTeX
If you process the code below, all four vboxes are exactly the same and have the same dimensions, unless you uncomment the %\toomuchtext command. The fourth box will then have an overflow, though the dimensions are defined and reported correctly. TeX then reports a "Overfull \vbox (24.63368pt too high) detected at line 21". This is the "overflow".
Here is the question: How may I catch the value "24.63368pt" from the message and refeed it automatically into my code? The result should be like: "\vtopsize=252.944pt + 24.63368pt = 277,57768 pt"
\newdimen\vtopsize
\vtopsize=252.944 pt %should be later: 277,57768pt
\newdimen\hboxsize
\hboxsize=180.666 pt
\parindent=0pt
\def\text{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.   Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text. Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text. Some text. Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.Some text. Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.Some text. Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text. Some text.(.) }
\def\toomuchtext{{\bf Too much text. Too much text. Too much text. Too much text. Too much text.  Too much text. Too much text. Too much text. }}
{\bf First example}
\vskip\baselineskip 
\hbox {\vtop to \vtopsize{\hsize=\hboxsize \text\vskip\baselineskip \vfill vtopsize= \the\vtopsize \vskip0.2\baselineskip hboxsize= \the\hsize} \hskip40pt
\vtop to \vtopsize{\hsize=\hboxsize  \text\vskip\baselineskip \vfill vtopsize= \the\vtopsize \vskip0.2\baselineskip hboxsize= \the\hsize}
 }%end of hbox
 \vskip3\baselineskip
 {\bf Second example}
\vskip\baselineskip 
 \hbox {\vtop to \vtopsize{\hsize=\hboxsize \text\vskip\baselineskip \vfill vtopsize= \the\vtopsize \vskip0.2\baselineskip hboxsize= \the\hsize\vfill} \hskip40pt
\vtop to \vtopsize{\hsize=\hboxsize   \text
%question is here
%\toomuchtext %uncomment
%question is here
\vskip\baselineskip \vfill vtopsize= \the\vtopsize \vskip0.2\baselineskip hboxsize= \the\hsize \vskip0.2\baselineskip\vfill}
 }%end of hbox
 \vfill
 \bye


Example for measuring boxes
  (\jobname.tex)

\newcount\boxnum
\boxnum=11
{\bf Boxsizes}
\loop\vskip0.2\baselineskip 
\setbox11=\vtop to 1in{\hsize=1in \sl Here is Box \the\boxnum}%
\setbox12=\vtop{\hsize=1in \sl Here is Box \the\boxnum}%
\setbox13=\vbox{\hsize=1in \sl Here is Box \the\boxnum}%
\setbox14=\vbox to 1in{\hsize=1in \sl Here is Box \the\boxnum}%
\setbox15=\vbox{\hsize=1in}%
\setbox16=\vbox to 1in{\hsize=1in}%
{{\bf Box \the\boxnum }\vskip0.2\baselineskip%
\vskip0.2\baselineskip }\vskip0.2\baselineskip %
 ht \the\ht\boxnum%
 \vskip0.2\baselineskip %
wd \the\wd\boxnum%
 \vskip0.2\baselineskip %
dp \the\dp\boxnum%
\vskip\baselineskip%
\advance\boxnum by 1%
 \ifnum\the\boxnum<16\repeat%
 \bye


wht do you have to \vtopsize at all? if you did not have that then you would get no warning, and the box would do as you wish and grow to the natural size. You could measure then set \vtopsize and then reset forcing to the size it used naturally, but this seems a complicated circle to go round

Also vtopsize is a dimen, as is the to component of vbox: they can not have a plus component as you ask

should plus meant to be +? otherwise, how to make sense of the =?

@David Carlisle
It is a kind of fiddeling around with the overflow. I do not like, if the vboxes do not obey the given values (by having the overflow),  but they do. After clearing this, I might get to an average, which might be easier to handle. As usual: This is not something, I would directly use in a document, I'm just experimenting. The "natural size" of vboxes leads to an overflow, which is not limited by the given dimensions.

@cfr
Yes . It was just an example.

since plus means something different from +, you should change the example if you mean +/

I do not understand the comment. A vbox  with no to specification is never overfull

@David Carlisle
I am not sure about this, but the fourth column has an overflow in any case, because the text flows over the specified dimensions of the \vtop box. But, without the "to" specification, it is not reported in the console. And, as you can see by the values displayed, the extended box does not increment the values. So, the \vtop box is lengthened visually, but not de facto.

I'm not sure what your goal is here, but check page 387 of the TeX Book, or maybe \vsplit. Neither of these answer your question, but they might be solve the problem that you're having.

"The "natural size" of vboxes leads to an overflow," a vbox without to is never overfull as it is set natural height (which is what you are asking to do) but then of course that box is larger so its parent box may be overfull if it is a fixed height box.

@Max Chernoff Thanks for the hint, but I do not want the boxes to split.

Now, how about the question?

I don't understand why you say the box 'has an overflow in any case'. if you don't specify to, there is no specified dimension to exceed, so there cannot be an 'overflow'. there is nothing to overflow. (obviously, it could exceed the width, say, but it can't overflow vertically.) of course, if you do specify the to, the contents can exceed the specified dimension and that is reported. if you don't specify it, there is no excess to report. the box is never 'lengthened visually but not de facto'. I don't know enough tex to say, but I don't think that's possible.

I have added an example, how I can measure the boxes \ht \wd \dp. But I do not get, how to measure the current box, in the first example, the last column or \vtop.

The discussion does not focus on the question.

i fear you may be asking two questions: one, why the overfull box is not reported; two, if it is reported, how to catch the dimension to make a further measurement...

@jarnowic
"one, why the overfull box is not reported".  I did not ask that. The discussion went that way. See another comment below.

In this example, one may have displayed the measures of the current cell in this self-constructed table and have the "overfull" messages within the document.
\vskip\baselineskip
        \parindent=0pt
        \hoffset-0in
        \hsize=6.5in%from plain.tex
        \vsize=8.9in%from plain.tex
        \raggedright
        \newcount\info

        \newcount\columns
        \columns=1%do notchange
        \newcount\floors
        \floors=0%floor is just another name for a line
        \newcount\collimit
        \newcount\cells
        \cells=0
  \newcount\boxnum
        \boxnum=0
        \newcount\linelimit
        \linelimit=1
         \newcount\tables
        \tables=0
        \newdimen\csize
        \newdimen\cellheight
  \newdimen\cellwidth
        \cellheight=\vsize \divide\cellheight by \linelimit
        \def\ault{Error}
\newbox\mybox{}

\info=0 %only content
\info=1%cellnumbers with measuring and \cells
%
                %start conditional
        \collimit=1%limit must be defined before condition
\def\condition[#1,#2,#3]#4{
\ifnum\columns>\collimit\else\ifnum\the\tables=#1 \ifnum\the\floors=#2 \ifnum\the\columns=#3  #4
\ifnum\info=1\setbox\mybox=\vtop{\hsize=\csize\leavevmode\ignorespaces #4\vfill} \vskip0.2\baselineskip\vtop{
 {\bf Measuring: (\the\cells )}\vskip0.2\baselineskip
ht \the\ht\mybox 
\vskip0.2\baselineskip
wd \the\wd\mybox 
\vskip0.2\baselineskip
dp \the\dp\mybox
\ifdim\dp\mybox>\cellheight {\vskip0.2\baselineskip\bf You wanted dp \the\cellheight pt now it is dp \the\dp\mybox Overfull box?} \else \fi
\vskip\baselineskip
}\fi 
\fi\fi\fi\fi
}%
%beg conditionals
 \def\conditionals{
\condition[1,1,1]{24 24 24 24 24 24 224 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 244 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424}%
\condition[1,1,2]{24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24}%
\condition[1,1,3]{24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24}%
\condition[1,1,4]{24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24}%
\condition[1,1,5]{24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24}% 
\condition[1,1,6]{24 24 24}%
\condition[1,1,7]{24 24 24}%
%
\condition[1,2,1]{242}
\condition[1,2,2]{242}
\condition[1,2,3]{24 }%
\condition[1,2,4]{ 2424 }%
\condition[1,2,5]{24 24 24}% 
\condition[1,2,6]{24 24 24}%
\condition[1,3,1]{ 24 }%
\condition[1,3,2]{24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 2424 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24}%
%
}%end conditionals
\def\cell{\global\advance\cells by 1 \vtop  {\hsize=\csize\leavevmode\ignorespaces \conditionals}\hskip4pt }
%
\def\floor{\vskip0.5\baselineskip\advance\floors by 1\hbox{\loop\cell \advance \columns  by 1\ifnum \columns<\collimit\repeat}\columns=1 \vskip\baselineskip} %floor is just another name for a line
%
\def\newtable#1#2{\vskip\baselineskip \linelimit=#1 \cellheight=\vsize \divide\cellheight by \the\linelimit  \collimit=#2 \csize=\hsize \divide\csize by\collimit \advance\tables by 1\floors=0 \loop \floor \ifnum\the\floors<#1\repeat }
%end of defnitions
 \TeX
\newtable{6}{4}%lines and columns
\bye


Downvoting without a comment is senseless.

if i may add a comment: an example might not be an answer...

@jarnowic
Part of my question was, how to catch the value of the \message. In my answer, I showed, how to catch all the values \ht\wd\dp and to have them displayed in the document. Next step are the calculations, to catch the differences. Next step will be, to refeed them into the code, if possible.  I do not think, this forces to set up a new question.

@MBE   It goes without saying that we are able to measure \ht, \dp and wd of boxes. This is normal TeX primitive level. You need not to present this idea by such complicated code from which isn't clear what you are answering. And moreover, this is not answer but a new question. It only follows from your comment.
